# Update the value of a dropdown base on a certain dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have 2 dropdowns. 
One dropdown is country. Another dropdown is currency.
I want to use jQuery to control the currency base on user selected country.
So whenever user change the country, the currency change.

My first step is trying to get the selected value (country name) when user choose it.

```
//Auto choose currency
    country = jQuery('#input_1_15 :selected').text();
    jQuery( "#input_1_15" ).change(function() {
      country = jQuery('#input_1_15 :selected').text();
    });
    alert(country);
```

But it does not print out the country name when user choose.
https://jsfiddle.net/uqvgsk6j/

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: sorry, i updated my question.

Comment: Move alert into a `change` handler

Comment: There should be a relation between to dropdown. Based on the relation value will be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same order use

```
$(function() {
    $("#input_1_15").on("change",function() {
      $("#input_1_16").get(0).selectedIndex=$(this).get(0).selectedIndex;
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks. I have same order. But France, German, Italy uses the same currency. Will your code work?

Comment: Only if you have 3 euro options.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/refan/LtcjzoLp/3/

if you can add data attribute to options:

```
<option data-cur="JPY" value="Nhật Bản">Nhật Bản</option>
```

---

```
jQuery("#input_1_15").change(function() {

  var selectedCurrency = $(this).find(":selected").data("cur");
  $("#input_1_16").val(selectedCurrency);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
  $("#input_1_15" ).on("change", function() {       
      document.getElementById("input_1_16").selectedIndex = document.getElementById("input_1_15").selectedIndex;
  });
});
```

[**your fiddle updated**](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/uqvgsk6j/4/)